# how to update foreign key

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have 2 tables; design of first table is like below:

**Table 1**:

```
    id_Doc_line_sheet (pk),Autonumber
    DocNo (text)
    lineNo (text)
    Sheet No (text)
```

Combination of fields (DocNo, lineNo, Sheet No) is index and unique.

Design of second table is like below:

**Table 2**:

```
  id_Doc_line_trans (pk), Autonumber
  id_Doc_line_sheet (fk),Number
  name
```

Now in table1, for the field lineNo I have records with leading spaces and without leading spaces like below:

```
  id_Doc_line_sheet            DocNo        lineNo      Sheet No    
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
  1001                         doc-0001    line-0001    1
  1002                         doc-0001     line-0001   1
  1003                         doc-0001    line-0001    2
  1004                         doc-0001     line-0001   2
  1005                         doc-0002    line-0002    1
  1006                         doc-0002     line-0002   1
  1007                         doc-0001    line-0005    1
  1008                         doc-0001     line-0005   1
```

And I want deleted these records with leading spaces but at first I want to update (id_Doc_line_sheet) for each unique (DocNo,lineNo,Sheetno) to correct one (without leading space).
 I mean if the table2 is like below:

```
    id_Doc_line_trans     id_Doc_line_sheet     name
    ---------------------------------------------------
     1                        1001              name01
     2                        1002              name02
     3                        1003              name03
     4                        1004              name04
     5                        1007              name07
     6                        1008              name08
```

I update (id_Doc_line_sheet) to something like below:

```
id_Doc_line_trans     id_Doc_line_sheet     name
---------------------------------------------------
 1                     1001                name01
 2                     1001                name02
 3                     1003                name03
 4                     1003                name04
 5                     1007                name07
 6                     1007                name08
```

And then delete records with leading spaces from first table.

Please help how I can do it?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Access? They are very different databases.

Comment: my tables are in sql-server as a back-end and the queries are in Ms access as a front-end,

Comment: if i could know solution in both will be very helpful, but any way if i could know solution for one of these databases will be okey for me because i need update query for updating my table one time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I understood, it seems you want to update the `table2` based on the `sheet_no` first `id` used. If so, you can use the following:

**Explanation**

1. You need to get the first record in `table1` based on the `sheet_no` using `report` cte
2. Find the corresponding `sheet_no` for each row in `table2`
3. Update the `table2` entries where `row_number =1`

**Query**

```
;with report as(
   select row_number() over(partition by sheet_no order by id_doc_line_sheet) as [Row],id_doc_line_sheet,sheet_no
   from table1       
   where line_no not like ' %' -- here you can ensure that lin_no doesn't start with leading space
), combined as(
    select t2.id_doc_line_trans,
           t2.id_doc_line_sheet,
           t1.sheet_no
    from table2 t2
    inner join table1 t1 on t2.id_doc_line_sheet = t1.id_doc_line_sheet
)

update t set t.id_doc_line_sheet = r.id_doc_line_sheet
from report r 
inner join combined c on r.sheet_no = c.sheet_no
inner join table2 t on t.id_doc_line_trans = c.id_doc_line_trans
where r.[Row]=1
```

result after updating `table2`

```
    id_doc_line_trans   id_doc_line_sheet   name
    1   1001    name01
    2   1001    name02
    3   1003    name03
    4   1003    name04
```

Then you can apply the delete statement based on your requirements

Here a working [demo](http://rextester.com/FYUA14320)

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks, how i have to be sure in this statement (update t set t.id_doc_line_sheet = r.id_doc_line_sheet) ,r.id_doc_line_sheet is related to line No that has no leading space, in the sample (table1) id_doc_line_sheet is related to line no without  leading space and it works, but in my database i am not sure always first record is related to line no without leading space.

Comment: you can add to the criteria the following `and line_no not like ' %'`

Comment: thanks is it possible modify your Answer regarding your new commnet

Comment: the answer i received assume for each Doc No, Sheet No, i have similar Line no (with leading space or not leading space) but in my database i have different line no for each Doc No, Sheet No (as i edited in my question), the please help how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach which does not use analytic functions, which was the easiest way to approach this in my mind.  We can aggregate over `table1` and pivot out both the id of the records both with and without leading whitespace.  Also, we can check to make sure a given document/sheet even has such a page occurring.  Then, all we need to do is join `table2` to this first CTE to get the old and new id values in a single record.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        DocNo, [Sheet No],
        MAX(CASE WHEN [lineNo] LIKE ' %' THEN id_Doc_line_sheet END) AS id_old,
        MAX(CASE WHEN [lineNo] NOT LIKE ' %' THEN id_Doc_line_sheet END) AS id_new
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY DocNo, [Sheet No]
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN [lineNo] LIKE ' %' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        t1.id_Doc_line_trans, t1.id_Doc_line_sheet, t1.name, t2.id_old, t2.id_new
    FROM table2 t1
    INNER JOIN cte1 t2
        ON t1.id_Doc_line_sheet = t2.id_old
)

UPDATE cte2
SET id_Doc_line_sheet = id_new;
```

Note that the update logic is trivial; all the information and records of interest were already included in the second CTE.

### Demo

Comment: thanks Tim, both answers solved my problem, but i can select one as my answer, for increasing reputation score of mona like you, i  accept mona as my answer.

Comment: the answer i got depends on

Comment: the answer i received assume for each Doc No, Sheet No, i have similar Line no (with leading space or not leading space) but in my database i have different line no for each Doc No, Sheet No (as i edited in my question), the please help how to solve the problem.

Comment: @MasoudSedighi In general you should not change your question like this, as it can draw downvotes.  I will leave my answer here as a valid response to your original question.