# how to update foreign key that depends on 3 field in primary table

Tags: sql-server

before i had a similar question for update foreign key that depends on 2 fields in primary table, [how to update foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483910/how-to-update-foreign-key)

after getting answer and testing in my database, i saw it did not solve my problem, actually the answer i received assume for each Doc No, Sheet No, i have similar Line no (with leading space or not leading space) but in my database i have different line no for each Doc No, Sheet No (as i edited in my question) so i modified my question and sample data like below for getting new Answer:

I have 2 tables; design of first table is like below:

**Table 1**:

```
    id_Doc_line_sheet (pk),Autonumber
    DocNo (text)
    lineNo (text)
    Sheet No (text)
```

Combination of fields (DocNo, lineNo, Sheet No) is index and unique.

Design of second table is like below:

**Table 2**:

```
  id_Doc_line_trans (pk), Autonumber
  id_Doc_line_sheet (fk),Number
  name
```

Now in table1, for the field lineNo I have records with leading spaces and without leading spaces like below:

```
  id_Doc_line_sheet            DocNo        lineNo      Sheet No    
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
  1001                         doc-0001    line-0001    1
  1002                         doc-0001     line-0001   1
  1003                         doc-0001    line-0001    2
  1004                         doc-0001     line-0001   2
  1005                         doc-0002    line-0002    1
  1006                         doc-0002     line-0002   1
  1007                         doc-0001    line-0005    1
  1008                         doc-0001     line-0005   1
```

And I want deleted these records with leading spaces but at first I want to update (id_Doc_line_sheet) for each unique (DocNo,lineNo,Sheetno) to correct one (without leading space).
 I mean if the table2 is like below:

```
    id_Doc_line_trans     id_Doc_line_sheet     name
    ---------------------------------------------------
     1                        1001              name01
     2                        1002              name02
     3                        1003              name03
     4                        1004              name04
     5                        1007              name07
     6                        1008              name08
```

I update (id_Doc_line_sheet) to something like below:

```
id_Doc_line_trans     id_Doc_line_sheet     name
---------------------------------------------------
 1                     1001                name01
 2                     1001                name02
 3                     1003                name03
 4                     1003                name04
 5                     1007                name07
 6                     1007                name08
```

And then delete records with leading spaces from first table.

Please help how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the new requirements you provided

Here what you can do

1. Find all the lines with no leading space, this is where `report` cte was used for
2. apply the result `report` to the `table1` by joining the `sheet_no` and `doc_no` and line_no of `table` =  `' ' + report.line_no + %` , here where `combined` cte was used
3. update the table2 based on the id_doc_line_sheet of the `combined` replaceId

**Query**

```
;with report as(
   select t.id_doc_line_sheet, sheet_no,doc_no,line_no
   from @table1 t
   where t.line_no not like ' %'
), combined as(
   select isnull(x.id_doc_line_sheet,t.id_doc_line_sheet) replaceId, t.id_doc_line_sheet,t.doc_no,t.line_no,t.sheet_no
   from @table1 t
   left join report x on x.sheet_no = t.sheet_no and
                          x.doc_no = t.doc_no and 
                          t.line_no like ' ' + x.line_no + '%'
)

update t2 set t2.id_doc_line_sheet = c.replaceId
from @table2 t2
inner join combined c on c.id_doc_line_sheet = t2.id_doc_line_sheet
```

Here a working [demo](http://rextester.com/BWSWII93225)

Result

```
id_doc_line_trans   id_doc_line_sheet   name
1   1001    name01
2   1001    name02
3   1003    name03
4   1003    name04
5   1007    name07
6   1007    name08
```

If this is not what you are looking for, kindly explain in more details the criteria how the query should update the table2.

Hope this will help you

Comment: it seems you have not used report cte in your code,like what you explain in the top of answer is ok?

Comment: it should not be (left join report x on x.sheet_no = t.sheet_no and
                          x.doc_no = t.doc_no and 
                          t.line_no like ' ' + x.line_no + '%')

Comment: i fixed the code, explain more about your data, we cannot predict what you want at the end, what I did so far, analyzing your data

Comment: Thank you very much, right now i do not have access to main database, but now i checked with sample data and it works for me